# Double tap over collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView and a UICollectionView.
 
The way it works is that when I click on the TableView, the contents of the CollectionView has be changed and everything works fine.
 
However, when I add a UITapGestureRecognizer over the entire View for the double click, everything still works as it should, but the CollectionView loads significantly slower.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
             tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
             tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
             tap.delaysTouchesBegan = true
             view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

The issue is the line: `tap.delaysTouchesBegan = true`
If true, the CollectionView is slow. In case it's false, everything is fast, but double click doesn't work :(
 
Any experience, idea?

Comment: I've added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for double-taps to a `UICollectionView` and I didn't need to set `delaysTouchesInView` to `true` for it to work. And I just don't see how the loading speed of the collection view could possibly be affected by the tap gesture in any way.

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, only in TableView double-click works without delaysTouchesInView = true and everything is OK. But I need double-click over the entire view and not just in the TableView. Any idea?